# How to get metadata from ActivityInfo?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I want to read activity metadata from another app. I have cole like this:

```
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MY_ACTION);

        List<ResolveInfo> pluginsInfo = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);

        for (ResolveInfo plugin : pluginsInfo) {
                ResolveInfo info = plugin;
                ActivityInfo aInfo = info.activityInfo;

                Bundle metadata = aInfo.metaData;
        }
```

And sometimes it works good, but sometimes metadata is null. On same emulator and same app version. Is there other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And answer is simple:
packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER | **PackageManager.GET_META_DATA**);